# How to compute the resistance of this metallic part (steel angle iron), for a joist fitted in an I-profile beam?

Tags: materials, beam, material-science, building-design, building-physics

Let's say we have an oak joist (15 cm x 15 cm x 370 cm), which is "fitted" in the profile of an I-profile beam (height 140 mm, width 66 mm), and the surface where the joist is laid is **too small**. We would like to fix this.

Among many possible solutions, I would like to study the right dimensions for the following **blue metallic** part.

[image]

Hypothesis:

- the joist has to support 500 kg
- we neglect the question of the resistance of the I-profile beam here
- the blue metallic part is taken from a steel angle iron, but cut to have the desired shape:

  [image]

**Question: is a 100 x 100 mm (thickness 10 mm), and 20 cm length, steel angle iron enough?**

How to calculate this?

The stress is probably this one:

[image]

Comment: Don't neglect the bolts through the wood.  There's a reason metal bracketry generally tries to support the wood from below.  Wood will get split if you load it as you have shown.  Look up "joist hanger"

Comment: Is the oak resting on the lower flange of the i-beam? if so then the  angle and bolts are just to secure the oak beam.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, the oak joist is resting on the lower flange of the i-beam. Only a few centimenters (and it seems to not have moved in the last 100 years, but still want to secure it).  So the steel angle iron will not support any weight, it is just an extra security.

Comment: @Abel Yes that's right, it could split the wood. I have seen many joist hangers, but not one that could both support the wood from below and have an angle that could land on the upper side of the i-beam.

Comment: @Abel 2/2 On the other hand, since the oak joist is resting on the lower flange of the i-beam, the angle is just an extra security, it doesn't support weight. But *even in this case*, you might be right: the simple facts of drilling holes for bolts in the oak at the left end of the joist might weaken it, is that right?

Comment: Just drilling holes shouldn't have a big impact, if the holes are small enough.  The I-beam is usually significantly thicker than any joist hanger you would use and so there generally is no need to attach to the upper side specifically.  If the beam is resting on the lower lip, just add two L brackets to keep it in place.  Think of the wood beam as a bundle of sticks with the sticks in the direction of the grain.